# Copy files from listbox to another directory

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and what I'm trying to do is

1. Search for a file
2. List all matching files into a listbox
3. Copy the whole folder where the file is located to another place

I found bits and pieces on the web that I'm using. Right now it's only the btn_search_Click part that is working.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                //Directory to search in
                DirectoryInfo Di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\xxxx\Versionen");
                FileInfo[] nPfad = Di.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                Int32 nLengePfad = nPfad.GetLength(0);
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(nPfad);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found");

            }

        }
        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string sourceFile = @"D:\Users\Public\public\test.txt";
                string destinationFile = @"D:\Users\Public\private\test.txt";

                // To move a file or folder to a new location:
                System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

                // To move an entire directory. To programmatically modify or combine
                // path strings, use the System.IO.Path class.
                System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Public\public\test\", @"C:\Users\Public\private");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question now is, what would the code look like, if I want to select a file from the listbox and copy NOT the file but the folder it's located in to another place. I already have set a btn_save and a basic code to move files, but I need someone to show me a way to copy any selected file from the listbox or rather copy the folder of the selected file.

I'm fairly new to C# and am open for new approaches. If I'm completely wrong with the code, scratch it, show me a correct or easier way to achieve the same

Comment: `Copy the whole folder where the file is located to another place` - where the **file** or **files**? Can you better explain the last step?

Comment: Look at the Path class - you can extract locations of files from that, use that on the list in the listbox - assuming you kept the full path on it to determine the folder, now apply the routines you have to copy files etc.

Comment: So the thing is, somewhere on the Drive (idk where, that's why I search for them) are the source files (each folder containts 1 File and there are many Folders I need). I need to search for them and copy them to a directory

Answer (score 1):

You can move directly the directory with [Directory.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using the [FileInfo.DirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) you can get the Directory path from the `FileInfo[]` SelectedItems.

```
var itemsToMove = myListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<FileInfo>();
var directoriesTheyAreIn = itemsToMove.Select(x => x.DirectoryName);

var cleanDirectoriesList = directoriesTheyAreIn.Distinct();
//As many file can be in the same Dir we only need to move the dire once to move those file.
```

But what if Dir contains both selected and unselected files? Here I will move them all.

```
foreach (var path in cleanDirectoriesList)
{
    // here you have to craft your destination directory
    string destinationDirectory = "";
    Directory.Move(path, destinationDirectory);
}
```

From your question it's unclear what part of the old path should be keep in the new path. but if it's based on your `"D:\xxxx\Versionen"` string you can simply [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) this part with the new root path `"NewRoot\foo\bar"`:

```
 string destinationDirectory = path.Replace(@"D:\xxxx\Versionen", @"G:\FooBAR\NEWPATH\");
```

If you need to move only the selected file you can blindly call [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) before copying each file, as it won't throw error if the directory already exist. Grouping on directory to avoid useless instruction could have been possible but I feel like it won't be that easy to modify. Here the code will simply be: create the directory then [move the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
foreach (var item in itemsToMove) {
    string destinationDirectory = @"BasedPath\" + " Craft it ";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);
    File.Move(item.FullName, destinationDirectory + item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thx for that one, I kinda changed my approach to make it easier for me, I actually dont need the list box nor message boxes. What I'm trying to achieve right now is, search for the file and copy the file to a new directory. That's all I need

Answer (score 0):

Store the list of files into a `List<FileInfo>` and iterate through with `foreach`. This worked for me:

```
        string destination = @"C:\Some\Destination\";
        string actualFile = string.Empty;
        foreach (var file in fileList)
        {
            actualFile = file.FullName;
            File.Copy(actualFile, destination + Path.GetFileName(actualFile));
        }
```